# Can we make our public iOS app access to private organization?

Tags: ios, apple-business-manager

I am facing one issue here. I have my iPad and that is managed by Apple Business Manager(ABM) portal. Currently I am logged-in with ABM account and when I am searching the public app which I have created that is not listed in the search option.

Do we have any way to share the public app there? Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong here.

NOTE: I must need this app as public release and I want to allow private organization to use my app. Is this possible?

Comment: Is your app available in the country where your ABM account is registered?  Have you set the type in the filter to "iPhone" or "iPad"?  That seems to help the search.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes ABM account is registered in the same country where the app is available. I am using my iPad to search the public app and the app support both iPhone and iPad versions.

Comment: What I mean is, in the search box, select the "filter" icon and select iPad or iPhone as the media type.  I just tried and I couldn't find one of my apps until I selected "iPhone" specifically in the filter

Comment: Okey let me try that way. Thanks